# Install matplotlib module in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation

I am trying to install matplotlib in python. But getting `ModuleNotFoundError`.

I tried installing matplotlib in the linux command prompt with

```
sudo pip install matplotlib
```

I got the message:

> Successfully installed matplotlib-2.2.4

But I could not find the package in Linux.

Also when I try to import it in Python I am getting

```
import matplotlib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

I expect matplotlib to be installed but I have the error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named 'matplotlib'

Comment: Share the whole error log please when running pip install matplotlib

Answer (score 1):

> $ sudo pip install matplotlib

You may as well `$ sudo pip uninstall matplotlib` since that's not doing you any good.

Using `sudo` changes your environment.
In particular it may change `$PATH`
and hence change the output of `$ which python`,
which matters for your `import`.
The env var `PYTHONPATH` can also be relevant,
as it affects `sys.path`.

Verify that `$ which python` and `$ python --version` return what you expect.

Issue these commands:

```
$ python -m pip install matplotlib
$ python -c 'import matplotlib'
```

Expected output is that the `import` silently succeeds.

If you continue to have trouble,
inspect the `path` variable and `ls -l` the directories it mentions:

```
$ python
>>> import pprint, sys
>>> pprint.pprint(sys.path)
```

Consider using [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/) to manage your library dependencies.